# Typescript hierarchy of a sharable module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to write a package in Typescript such that once I compile it into .js, the typing is also available if you use it in a Typescript application.

Here is an example of a Http client that is built on top of Axios:

```
// http.ts
import Axios, {AxiosInstance, AxiosPromise, AxiosRequestConfig} from 'axios';
import {HttpStatic} from './interfaces';


export default class Http implements HttpStatic {
    private headers: object;
    private _client: AxiosInstance;

    constructor(options?: AxiosRequestConfig) {
        options = Object.assign({}, options);
        this.headers = {};
        this._client = Axios.create(options);
    }

    public get<R>(url: string, params: object = {}, headers: object = {}): AxiosPromise<R> {
        return this._client.get(url, {
            headers: {
                ...this.headers,
                ...headers
            }, params
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the interface:

```
// interface.d.ts
import {AxiosPromise, AxiosRequestConfig} from 'axios';

export interface HttpInstance {
    new(uri: string, options?: AxiosRequestConfig):HttpStatic
    get<R>(url: string, params: object, headers: object): AxiosPromise<R>;
}

export interface HttpStatic {
}
```

When I compile this, I get `http.js` and `http.d.ts`. But `http.d.ts` is basically the `http.ts` file and includes the line `import {HttpStatic} from './interfaces'` which does not exist in the `dist` folder.

So when I try to use this module, I get errors saying `./interfaces` not found.

Now, if I put all the content of the `./interfaces` inside the `http.ts` then everything will compile fine. But I don't want to do that, and I rather to keep the interface/types separate from the source code.

How do I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't you also have an `interfaces.d.ts` file generated? What command line and `tsconfig.json` are you using to generate the `http.d.ts` and `http.js` files?

Comment: It does not. I'm using webpack

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want/expect, this is one of those situations in which you will need to dig a little deeper, as this is pretty fundamental TypeScript functionality and your problem is that webpack is sitting in the middle doing ... something.

Comment: Why is it interface.d.ts and not interface.ts ? Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem and contains your setup. A repo, etc.